# Data Mining Assignment

Tags: python

I have been asked to complete this assignment and I am having great difficulty with it, can anyone help? "Write a Python program that asks the user to enter a stock data file name (.csv format) [similar in structure to the 'stockdata.csv' file given under 'Course Materials'], asks for the column number, and then reads the file, totals the value in the specified column. Then the program should print the average value of the specified column."

```
#initialize variables
column = 0
fh = 0

#function1
def openfile():
    while True:
        fname = raw_input ("Enter File Name: ")
        try:
            fhand = open(fname)
        except:
            print "File not found. Enter valid file name."
            continue
        break
    return fhand

#function2
def processfile (f,c):
    tot = 0.0
    count = 0
    for line in f:
        anyline = line.split(',')
        if line.startswith('Date'):
            continue
        tot = tot + float(anyline[c])
        count = count + 1
    avg = tot/count
    print "Column Average: ", avg

#main
fh = openfile()
while True:
    column = raw_input('Enter column number: ')
    try:
        column = int(column)
    except:
        print "Please Enter A Valid Input"
        continue
    break
processfile(fh, column)
```

But this gives me the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/ex50/tests/stockdatafile.py", line 40, in <module> processfile(fh, column)     
File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/ex50/tests/stockdatafile.py", line 27, in processfile avg = tot/count ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

, can anyone help?

Comment: What are the errors you get

Comment: the errors that I am getting are

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/ex50/tests/stockdatafile.py", line 40, in <module>
    processfile(fh, column)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/ex50/tests/stockdatafile.py", line 27, in processfile
    avg = tot/count
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

Comment: Are you sure that the file is not empty and that at least one line doesn't start with the string `"Date"`?

Comment: as @Matthias said, check your file, or post a snippet or example of it here for us to view.

Comment: The first line of the file is "Date, Open, High, Low, Close" and beneath that begins numbers for all of those values

Comment: Double check your input file. Make sure your delimiter is correct when splitting the line. The file you mention is a csv, but there is no exact 'CSV Format' the delimiter may not necessarily be comma

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to your `processfile` function, the for loop does not run completly. This in turn means your `count` and `tot` variable stays at `0` and `0.0`

When `avg = tot/count` is then run, you get the error as you are attempting to divide the float `tot` which is still `0.0` by `0`